# Частица "да" в речи русскоязычных армян

Tags: лексика, фонетика, диалекты

В речи русскоязычных армян (в данном случае речь идет о бакинских) в побудительных предложениях очень распространена частица **да.** Примеры:

**Скажи да...**

**Принеси да...**

**Ладно да...**

**Прекратите да...**

Поскольку в словарях такое значение не зафиксировано, мне интересно, распространена ли эта частица в речи самих русских? Если да, в каких диалектах? Употребляете ли Вы эту частицу в этом значении?

P. S. Частица эта произносится слитно со словом. Иными словами, эта частица в большинстве случаев употребляется вместо слова **"пожалуйста"**.

Дополнение

Во всех примерах, которые привели участники, частица "да" стоит после вопросительного предложения". В этом значении она фиксируется словарями.

Однако в моих примерах частица всегда стоит после глагола в повелительном наклонении и всегда выражает вежливую просьбу.

-

### Обновление

Чтобы было понятней, о чём идет идет речь, прикрепляю [видео](https://youtu.be/VKZE6Qn7FM0?t=20). **Обратите внимание, как говорит на 20–21 секундах.**

Comment: не менее интересно, эквивалентом какого именно явления в кавказских и центрально-азиатских языках выступает эта частица

Comment: Прочитайте в интернете про бакинский акцент. А также в ютубе можете посмотреть шутливые видео Розы и Врубеля. Они как раз копируют бакинцев.Сразу поймете.

Comment: Видео в моем вопросе.

Comment: не услышал в видео языковедческого комментария

Comment: Будьте внимательны: на 20-21 секунде.

Comment: Послушайте этот фрагмент: иду да, мозги не делай.

Comment: на этом моменте есть **языковедческий комментарий**? а что герои говорят на армянском или азербайджанском я не понимаю... вам, как армянину, полагаю, должно быть очевидно, какое явление армянского языка воспроизводится частицей "да"

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94462/discussion-between--and---).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[«Я и подумала: зачем брать такие дорогие билеты, да?»](http://present-dv.ru/obraz/slova-parazity-i-ih-hozyaeva-282)**

> Употребление частицы «да» с вопросительной интонацией в данном случае
>   не подразумевает ответа собеседника – говорящий его не ждет и не
>   оставляет в речи пауз для этого. Человек, часто употребляющий
>   слово‑паразит «да» в конце предложения, просто неосознанно ищет
>   поддержки у того, кто с ним говорит. С помощью своего «да» он как бы
>   фиксирует внимание на своих словах, цепляя собеседника этим крючочком.

**[Намеренное использование сорных слов](http://vashgolos7.ru/kak-izbavitsya-ot-privychki-upotreblyat-slova-parazity.html)**

> Для кого-то такой стиль общения является частью их образа. Есть люди,
>   намеренно вставляющие слова-паразиты в свою речь. Это бывает вполне
>   уместным.

В своем большинстве, это слова со слабым лексическим значением:

- местоимения (это, как его);
- частицы (указательная — вот, модальная - пожалуй, вопросительная — да, утвердительная — значит, сравнительная — как бы, резюмирующая — ну).

  ---

Частное наблюдение (**[Казанский диалект татаро-русского](https://mamonino.livejournal.com/817667.html)**):

> Казанцы считают, что вопрос не прозвучит полноценно, если в конце к
>   нему не добавить "ДА". Пример: "Этот автобус идет до вокзала, да?"
>
> ---

Я не употребляю; в паузах (в приватной беседе) могу позволить себе спаразитировать: "Ну и вот..."

В общем, сорные слова - это сугубо индивидуально.

Но вот такого "да"

> Напр.: принеси да стакан. Дай да книгу. Выпей да воды.

не слышала нигде и никогда (подолгу жила в Питере, Риге, местообитания - Москва), да ещё вместо "пожалуйста".

С уверенностью скажу, что это "да" - нерусское.

Comment: Я тоже никогда не слышал, поэтому стало интересно.

Comment: Так откуда же эта информация свалилась, Серж?

Comment: shampar, я не слышал в речи русских. Поэтому мне стало интересно,распространено ли это явление в России. В речи русскоязычных армян это явление достаточно распространено.

Comment: @Галина, я обновил свой вопрос, представил ссылку на видео. посмотрите, пожалуйста, чтобы было понятней.

Answer (score 2):

Распространена ли эта частица в речи самих русских? Чрезвычайно, и пик этого явления ещё не прошёл (под явлением имею в виду слово-паразит). Например, речь И. Прохоровой, телеведущей канала РБК-ТВ, грешит этим в каждой второй фразе. Не очень понятно побудительное начало в примерах — не слышно интонации, но в её случае (хотя мог бы назвать и другие) *ДА* работает на привлечение внимания и акцентирование мысли. Из-за высокой частотности такую речь чрезвычайно трудно воспринимать, даже если тема интересна. Жалко ваших ушей, но можете зайти на ГМ и убедиться: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XbcS8uj9Iic.

Comment: Употреблеие частицы "да" в ее речи, как раз описывается словарями. У нее частица "да" служит для потверждение ранней сказаной мысли. Оставим в стороне вопрос об избыточности употреблении этой частицы в ее речи.

Comment: Примеры с частицой "да", о которых говорю я, совершенно другие. Там нет паузы. Частица "да" здесь употребляется тогда, когда имеется в виду просьба.

Comment: Напр.: принеси да стакан. Дай да книгу. Выпей да воды.

Comment: Боюсь нарваться, но вы, похоже, о разных вещах. Подробности - в моем ответе.

Comment: И частота, и надобность такого подтверждения сказанного я не могу понять, объяснить, оправдать. Я соотнёс одно нелогичное с другим — армянским вывихом — и поставил их рядом, но если думаете, что это не сопоставимо (скорее так оно и есть), то корни надо искать в армянских заморочках.

Answer (score 2):

Вы об этом?

> — Дай мне пять молодых барашков, да? Я возьму от каждого по триста
>   грамм мяса, да? На хороший шашлык больше не возьмешь с барашка! Я
>   вымочу мясо в белом виноградном вине, да? Я дам его тебе — на,
>   красивая женщина, делай шашлык. И ты загубишь баранину!

(Ошибка резидента)
Так имитирует речь кавказца герой Ножкина Бекас.

https://www.ivi.ru/watch/oshibka_rezidenta/132277
(1:50:15 - и дальше).

Нет, для носителей русского как родного это нехарактерно.
Зато что-то подобное я слышал не только на Кавказе, но и в Средней Азии.

Значения "пожалуйста" я, впрочем, не наблюдал.
Это какое-то усилительное междометие, что ли...

А вот по ссылке shampar - там просто какой-то заменитель паузы.

Answer (score 2):

**"Да" наступает?**

Мне кажется, что это "да" похоже на **междометие со значениями "не правда ли, не так ли?"** или "**обратите внимание на это**", в речи оно выделяется паузами. А вот как это может выглядеть **в записи** (сайт "Эхо Москвы"):

Итак, «Родительское собрание» начинаем. Тема сегодня: «Российская школа как часть мирового образовательного процесса: победы и поражения». Наши гости сегодня **Александр Адамский, научный руководитель Института проблем образовательной политики «Эврика»**.

Цитаты из речи:

Так что, в общем, мне кажется, что не надо соблазняться словом «медаль», **– да?** – потому что там, допустим, золотых медалей больше.

Но связь между олимпиадными достижениями и уровнем массового образования для меня не так очевидна. Ну, это как в спорте. **Да?**

И 3-й сюжет: у нас очень развиты развивающие программы в дошкольном образовании. Не просто тупая подготовка к школе, – **да?** – а развивающие программы.

Answer (score 0):

Частица «да» после глагола, делающая её вежливой, заимствована с тюркских языков. В тюркских языках если после глагола стоит частица «да» то повелительный глагол сразу превращается в глагол-просьбу, причём частица пишется слитно. Например: глагол «бер» означает «дай» по русски, соответственно «берда» - «дай пожалуйста», или гель – приди; гельда – приди пожалуйста, айт – скажи; айтда скажи пожалуйста и т.д. Не удивительно, что с таким явлением сталкиваются на территориях проживания тюркских народов, будь то Кавказ или Средняя Азия.

Comment: Можете объяснить, как такое заимствование могло попасть в русский? Когда, при каких условиях сие стало возможным? Или хотя бы ссылку дать?

Comment: @Albert Lemann, вы ошибаетесь, полагая, что это заимствование. Явление, о котором идет речь, является ничем иным, как бакинским жаргоном.

Comment: И да, мы говорим о русском языке, а не о тюрских. Поэтому приводить тюрские глаголы в качестве русских непровомерно.